APIで取得したJSONデータの取り扱い方法
やりたいこと。
Vueにおいて、APIで取得したJSON形式のデータに対して、以下のことができるようにしたいです。
1）JSON形式であるかどうかの判定
2）JSON形式であった場合、どのようなKeyであるか一覧表示/もしくは必要なKeyがあるかの確認
3) JSON形式であった場合、ネストしていく方法
v-forではValueしか取得できません。
ソースコード
Vueソースコードです。
取得すると、data.responsesはProxy(object）型となります。
<script setup lang="ts">
  import axios from "axios";
  import { reactive } from "vue";

  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/api";

  const data = reactive({
    responses:""
  });

  axios.defaults.headers.get['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  axios.defaults.headers.get['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

  const getData = async () => {
    let result = await axios.get(url);
    data.responses = result.data;
    console.log(data.responses);
  }

</script>

<template>
  <h1>API 接続テスト</h1>
  <section>
    <button @click="getData">Request</button>
    <p v-if="data.responses">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in data.responses ">{{ item }}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>

